# Show users heading location(north,east west,soth) using Google Map SDK for iOS

Tags: ios7, gps, google-maps-sdk-ios, proximity, apple-maps

I am working on an application where is want to show the user his heading location, like in Apple maps (magnetic direction) which is a small triangle and will rotate as the user moves physically using the app. I am using Google Maps SDK and would like to know if Google provides this option, i have researched a bit but dint get. Also, their official Google Map App doesn't have the feature.

Also i would like to know if there is any other better option for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;` should works for your require.

Except you want this feature works well in China.